# Putting an underscore in a \label

Tags: cross-referencing, symbols, tex-core, labels

I am trying to use `pdflatex` to type set some files that have underscores in the `\label`. Such as `\label{abc_xyz}` and have been unsuccessful. I keep getting errors such as:

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again>
                   \protect
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\def\itt{\tt #1}
\def\litt#1{\tt #1\label{#1}}
\begin{document}
\itt{pqr_mno}
\litt{abc_xyz}
\litt{xyz_abc}
\end{document}
```

I have made several changes and all have been unsuccessful. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! An underscore in a label is generally safe, but it can become unsafe with some packages. Can you prepare a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates the issue?

Comment: without a MWE it's very hard to say, but a wild guess: you're loading `babel` with a language that changes something.....

Answer (score 19):

Usually the underscore with its standard catcode "subscript" (8) does not cause problems, if used inside `\label` or `\ref`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\section{Hello World}
\label{sec_hello}
See section \ref{sec_hello}.
\end{document}
```

Also shorthands of package `babel` are not a problem, because `babel` patches the `\label`/`\ref` system to add support for shorthands.

### Active underscore

Probably you are using a package that makes the underscore active.
Then it becomes more complicate. A workaround is `\string` to make the active underscore behave as normal character:

```
\label{sec\string_hello}
\ref{sec\string_hello}
```

Also the label name is written into the `.aux` file and read again at the end of document. Here the catcode should be restored:

```
\usepackage{atveryend}
\AfterLastShipout{\catcode`\_=12\relax}
```

If the unknown package makes the catcode of the underscore active before `\begin{document}`, then it should be inactive during the reading of the `.aux` file at the end of the preamble.

```
\ifnum\catcode`\_=\active
  \catcode`\_=12\relax
  \AtBeginDocument{\catcode`\_=\active}%
\fi
```

The complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\catcode`\_=\active
\def_{\textunderscore}

\usepackage{atveryend}
\AfterLastShipout{\catcode`\_=12\relax}
\ifnum\catcode`\_=\active
  \catcode`\_=12\relax
  \AtBeginDocument{\catcode`\_=\active}%
\fi
\begin{document}
\section{Hello World}
\label{sec\string_hello}
See section \ref{sec\string_hello}.
\end{document}
```

### Package `underscore`

Depending on the package that makes the underscore active, the scope of the activeness and the definition of the underscore, there might be more comfortable
ways. For example, package `underscore` makes the underscore active and that breaks the referencing system. But the package supports `babel`. The underscore behaves as shorthand and is supported, if babel is loaded:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{underscore}

\begin{document}
\section{Hello World}
\label{sec_hello}
See section \ref{sec_hello}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Here is a simple set of source that shows the problem. \itt works but \litt does not.

Comment: \documentclass[twoside]{article}
\begin{document}

\def\itt{\tt #1}

\itt{pqr\_mno}

\def\litt#1{\tt #1\label{#1}}

\litt{abc\_xyz}

\litt{xyz_abc}

\end{document}

Comment: @user2207980: That is a different matter, how to set the underscore in text mode. There are many ways: `\itt{pqr\_mno}`, `\itt{pqr\textunderscore mno}`; `\verb|pqr_mno|`; `\newcommand*{\itt}{\texttt{\detokenize{#1}}}`; package `underscore` etc.