# Are LaTeX's label names case-sensitive? Can label names contain spaces?

Tags: cross-referencing

According to *Guide to LaTeX*, 4th edition, when creating a `\label{name}`,

> The keyword *name* may be any combination of letters, numbers, or symbols.

Is the *name* of a label case-sensitive? Can the *name* contain spaces?

I'm asking because when using Vim's [snipmate TeX snippet](https://github.com/honza/vim-snippets/blob/master/snippets/tex.snippets), if I type `sec` and hit tab, I automatically get:

```
\section{section name}
\label{sec:section name}
```

Then when I enter the *section name* in the `\section`, Vim automatically puts the same text after the `sec:` portion of the `\label`. Since my sections are often multiple, capitalized words, the label name ends up containing spaces and are capitalized. For instance, I might get:

```
\section{Planned Testing}
\label{sec:Planned Testing}
```

Prior to allowing Snipmate in Vim automatically enter the label name based on the section name, I would have manually typed:

```
\section{Planned Testing}
\label{sec:planned_testing}
```

## Spaces not allowed

[Syntastic](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic) in Vim shows an error if a label name contains spaces.

Comment: As far as i know, they are case-sensitive. You shouldn't use whitespace, or underscores, or Umlauts (ä, ü) in your labels. TeX *will* convert them to something *funny*. Using XeTeX or LuaTeX you can use Umlauts in labels.

Comment: I use `\label{chap:chapter-name}`,`\label{sec:section-name}`,`\label{subsec:subsection-name}`,`\label{fig:figure-name}`,`\label{tab:table-name}`,`\label{eq:equation-name}`,`\label{lst:code-name}` and `\label{itm:important-note}` as shown in http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Labels_and_Cross-referencing and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12174/naming-latex-files-best-practice

Comment: @Johannes_B Why do you recommend not using underscores?

Comment: @texenthusiast Is there a reason you use hyphens instead of underscores? The two examples of multi-word labels in the first link you provided—[LaTeX/Labels and Cross-referencing](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Labels_and_Cross-referencing)—used underscores as opposed to hyphens—`\label{fig:my_figure}` and `\label{the_label}`.

Comment: @MatthewRankin you can use them as http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121416/putting-an-underscore-in-a-label/121438#121438, but sometimes one might get into troubles, see more http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18311/what-are-the-valid-names-as-labels/18312#18312. To eliminate all conflicts(to be safe all times), I gave my choice :).

Comment: @MatthewRankin As texenthusiast linked: to be safe, don't use those things that *might* get you in trouble.

Comment: Related [What to consider when naming labels to prevent errors ?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/109443/15717)

Answer (score 17):

> Is the *name* of a label case-sensitive? Can the *name* contain spaces?

Yes and yes.

References are stored as a macro using `\csname r@<name>\endcsname`, so anything allowed within `\csname`...`\endcsname` is valid (as reference, see [Understanding how references and labels work](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/111280/5764) and [What exactly do `\csname` and `\endcsname` do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39380/5764)). This includes a distinction between case (since, by nature `\macro` is different from `\Macro`, `\MaCRo`, `\MACRO`, ...).

As a small example consider:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\expandafter\def\csname some bizarre Name 123\endcsname{Stuff}
\begin{document}
\csname some bizarre Name 123\endcsname

\section{A section}\label{sec:A section}
See~\ref{sec:A section} and~\ref{sec:a section}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: although spaces are permitted in the name of a label, it's generally recommended that you not use them.  they have been known to cause problems in journal production, so if you are submitting an article for publication, it's best to stick to the simplest option that will get the job done reliably.

Comment: @barbarabeeton IIRC, what a label may contain has been dramatically relaxed some years ago. Is your recommendation still valid?

Comment: @DenisBitouzé -- I personally wouldn't/don't use spaces in labels.  Although I'm pretty sure the basic mechanisms accept them, I don't know the behavior of all packages, or of "external" scripts that may be applied.  And debugging really unusual situations that exceed my familiarity isn't my favorite form of recreation.  YMMV.