# No .bbl generated

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I am having issue with generating references using TeXworks. Bibtex does not generate .bbl file, and the citation in the pdf appears only with [?].

Here is my pdflatex code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
As is discussed in \cite{power}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{ref}
\end{document}
```

Here is my bibtex code with only one entry:

```
@misc{power,
title = {Compressive Sensing: The Big Picture},
author = {Carron, I.},
year = 2013,
howpublished = {\url{ https://sites.google.com/site/igorcarron2/cs#reconstruction}}
}
```

I compiled them in this manner: pdflatex, bibtex, pdflatex, pdflatex.
But the bibliography does not show and the citation is only [?]. What seems suspicious is that no .bbl file is generated although bibtex has been run many times. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Do you get any warning(s) after running `bibtex` or in any other stage of the compilation process?

Comment: Is your `bibtex` code in a file named `ref.bib`? Where is that file? Also, the sequence you probably need is `pdflatex, bibtex, pdflatex, pdflatex (2 runs of pdflatex` following `bibtex`). But that wouldn't explain the lack of the `bbl`.

Comment: No. bibtex runs smoothly without any warning. This is another point that I am confused: when I add some wrong codes (like drop a "}"), it still runs well without warning.

Comment: Yes, the bibtex code is in ref.bib, which is in the same file with the pdflatex file. I am sorry for the typo in the sequence. I did exactly the sequence you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

This is an attempt. Possible source of errors could be that your bib file was saved as `ref.bib.tex` and forgot to load `hyperref` package. Run the file via TeXworks either

```
PdfLaTeX+MakeIndeX+BibTeX  or XeLaTeX+MakeIndeX+BibTeX
```

Just in case for the commands wasn't set, this is what is set in my TeXworks and got the results.

Edit -> Preference --> Typesetting-->Tool Configuration,  Use + to add at the processing tools window.

```
Name      PdfLaTeX+MakeIndex+BibTeX
Program   texify.exe
Argument  --pdf
          --tex-option=$synctexoption
          $fullname


Name      XeLaTeX+MakeIndeX+BibTeX
Program   texify.exe
Argument  --pdf
          --engin=xetex
          $fullname
```

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
As is discussed in \cite{power}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{ref}
\end{document}
```

and ref.bib has

```
@misc{power,
title = {Compressive Sensing: The Big Picture},
author = {Carron, I.},
year = 2013,
howpublished = {\url{ https://sites.google.com/site/igorcarron2/cs#reconstruction}}
}
```

and .bbl generated

```
\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\bibitem{power}
I.~Carron.
\newblock Compressive sensing: The big picture, 2013.
\newblock \url{ https://sites.google.com/site/igorcarron2/cs#reconstruction}.

\end{thebibliography}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But there is a warning when I runs MakeIndex: Couldn't find input index file go nor go.idx. ("go" is the main file that I am running)

Comment: @Fred -- Maybe the command was not properly set. I have added my TeXworks system that run your case for your reference. Hope this will help.  See the update thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the same thing that TexWorks was not outputting a `.bbl` file even when running: `PdfLaTeX+MakeIndeX+BibTeX`.  The reason turned out to be a **--clean** option in the tool configuration.  As an earlier answer indicated, go to:

`Edit` --> `Preference` --> `Typesetting`-->`Tool Configuration`

and remove the **--clean** option for this command sequence.  When I did that, a number of intermediate files were left after compiling my LaTeX file including the `.bbl` file which is what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

I got the message `No file main.bbl.` because a label had an underscore:

```
    \label{def:term_value}
```

I fixed it by replacing the underscore by an hyphen:

```
    \label{def:term-value}
```

Comment: This [isn't generally a problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/121438/106162) and if you were doing something that made it an issue, it should cause an earlier error than `No file main.bbl.`