# How to do shell-escape in TeXWorks?

Tags: shell-escape

I know this question has been asked a lot of times, however I can't seem to fix my problem. My problem is as follows, I am using MikTex 2.9 and TeXWorks and I try to add the `--enable-write18` to enable shell-escape however the output gives:

```
texify: --enable-write18 unknown option
```

I added it to: Preferences > Typesettings and then pdfLaTeX and selected edit and then added it to the parameter list.

Thanks

Comment: With texify you must pass the option through the --tex-option option: `texify --tex-option=--shell-escape`

Comment: This might serve as a starting point -- http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/180748/34618

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With texify you must pass the option through the `--tex-option` option:

```
 texify --tex-option=--shell-escape  ....
```