# Shell Escape in Miktex 2.9 for CSVsimple

Tags: pdftex, miktex, shell-escape, csvsimple

I am quite new to LateX and I have been trying for the past few days to do a Shell escape in Miktex 2.9/ TeXworks in my pdflatex+Makeindex+bibtex typesetter so that I could be able to use the [CSVsorter](http://t-f-s.github.io/csvsorter/) presented in the [CSVsimple](http://osl.ugr.es/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/csvsimple/csvsimple.pdf) package.

I tried the methods presented [Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/187276/how-to-do-shell-escape-in-texworks), and [Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37489/how-can-i-enable-write-18-on-a-miktex-installation).

When I try to compile my tex

```
\csvreader[sort by=table/namesort.xml,
head to column names,
tabular=>{\color{red}}lllll,
table head=\toprule year of birth\\\midrule,
table foot=\bottomrule]
{./table/csvsimple-example.csv}{}{\csvlinetotablerow}
```

I obtain this error :

> sort "./table/csvsimple-example.csv" by "./table/namesort.xml">
>
> ("C:...\My tex.csvtoken"
>
> ! Package csvsimple Error: Call of CSV-Sorter failed! Use '-shell-escape' optio
>   n or check log file 'csvsorter.log'..
>
> See the csvsimple package documentation for explanation.
>   Type  H   for immediate help.
>   ...
>
> l.1 ...ption or check log file 'csvsorter.log'.}{}

But I have no log file to start with. So I don't know if it is a programming error or a problem to configure -shell-escape

Thank you

Comment: Have you been able to do the command line example from http://t-f-s.github.io/csvsorter/ ? That's everything between **Example** and **Example (continued for LaTeX)**. If that does not work, the problem is, maybe, the Java installation and not LaTeX.

Comment: CSVsorter works (I tried Example has ask) but I tried calling the csvsorter in latex has in the example (continued for LateX) and it didn't  I received this log : <sort "songcontest.csv" by "./sumsort.xml">
runsystem(csvsorter -c "./sumsort.xml" -l "csvsorter.log" -t "csvcmdex.csvtoken
" -i "songcontest.csv" -o "csvcmdex_sorted._csv" -q 1)...disabled (restricted).

("C:\Users\Simon.Aperture\Desktop\Test latex\cvs cdmex\csvcmdex.csvtoken"

! Package csvsimple Error: Call of CSV-Sorter failed! Use '-shell-escape' optio
n or check log file 'csvsorter.log'..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the command line version works for the OP, it looks like a TeXWorks setup problem.

The following additions to the TeXWorks compilation options work for me. I am sorry for german texts in the screenshots from my PC.

The first one is for setting up a pdfLaTeX compile option with `--shell-escape`:

[image]

The second one is for a pdfLaTeX+MakeIndex+BibTeX compile option with `--shell-escape`:

[image]

With both settings the example from http://t-f-s.github.io/csvsorter/ compile.

Prerequisite is that the `CSVsorter` program is found on the system path. Putting it into the source directory of the LaTeX example also works.

The files for the example are the following:

**songcontest.tex**:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,booktabs,csvsimple}
\usepackage{geometry}
\begin{document}

\csvreader[sort by=sumsort.xml,
  head to column names,
  tabular=lllcc,
  table head=\toprule\textbf{Artist} & \textbf{Title} & \textbf{Country} &
             \textbf{Points} & \textbf{TV+JV}\\\midrule,
  table foot=\bottomrule]
{songcontest.csv}{}
{\Artist & \itshape''\Title'' & \Country &
 \bfseries\the\numexpr\Televote+\Juryvote\relax & $(\Televote+\Juryvote)$}

\end{document}
```

**songcontest.csv**:

```
Title,Artist,Country,Televote,Juryvote
La la la la la,The Singers,United Kingdom,25,62
One and two and three,Hansi Unterober,Germany,47,35
Rarara,Channel Rats,Grand Fenwick,12,14
The green hills of the shire,Frodo and Friends,New Zealand,76,45
Paris e Calais,Chantal and Pascal,France,47,41
The bell rings,Baab,Sweden,87,24
```

**sumsort.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<csv>
  <sortlines>
    <sum order="descending" type="integer">
      <column name="Televote"/>
      <column name="Juryvote"/>
    </sum>
    <column name="Country" order="ascending" type="string"/>
  </sortlines>
</csv>
```

My example directory contains the following files:

[image]

Comment: I Tried exactly what you did and it worked but insode my main document it didn't. y file construction is a main tex file, and the xml and csv inside a seperate foleder named table

Comment: If it can help or change something, I can try to use winedt.

Also I use the memoir class.

Comment: @SimonBoucher If my answer worked for you, the question about 'shell escpae in MikTeX' is solved. There has to be some programming error in your main file, I guess. To get help in this matter, you should file a new question with a MWE which allows to reconstruct the problem.