# Error : I have a problem when I execute the following code

Tags: errors

I have a problem when I execute the following code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{book}%
\usepackage{graphicx,amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,mathptmx}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fancybox}   % définit des macros pour des boîtes, des cadres, etc.
\usepackage[svgnames,x11names,hyperref]{xcolor} % définit les couleurs par noms
\usepackage{colortbl,array}
\usepackage[section]{algorithm}   %Gère les algorithmes
\usepackage{algpseudocode} % Codes semblables à fortran ou pascal ou C
\usepackage{multicol,wrapfig,lmodern}
\usepackage[bf,textfont={footnotesize,it}]{caption}
\usepackage[toc,page,title,titletoc,header]{appendix}
\usepackage[margin=2cm,includefoot,includehead]{geometry}
\setlength{\parindent}{4ex}     % indentation au début de chaque paragraphe
\setlength{\parskip}{2ex plus 0.5ex minus 0.2ex} % espace vertical entre
\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=black,pageanchor]{hyperref}%
\usepackage[plainheadsepline,nouppercase]{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{{\thechapter. #1}}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{ \thesection.\ #1}{}}
\newcommand\chapterstring{Chapitre}
\usepackage{titlesec}
%
% chapitres dans un box
\titleformat{\chapter}[frame] {\bfseries\sffamily\color{Blue4}} {\filright
\enspace \Large \chapterstring~\thechapter} {14pt} {\Large\filcenter}

%
% sections avec rule
\titleformat{\section}{\vspace{0mm plus 1cm}\addpenalty{-1000}\color{Blue4}
\Large\bfseries\sffamily}{\thesection}{1em}{}[{\color{Blue4}\titlerule[0.5pt]}]
%
% sous-sections
\titleformat{\subsection}{\addpenalty{-500}\large\bfseries\sffamily}{
\thesubsection}{1em}{}
%
% sous-sous-sections
\titleformat{\subsubsection}{\penalty-500\vspace{0pt plus 2pt}{}\bfseries
\sffamily}{\thesubsubsection}{}{}[\vspace{-14pt}]

%
% Divers macros tcolorbox
%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Divers Box en couleur avec le package tcolorbox
% Faire attention à l'ordre des options!!!
\usepackage[theorems,minted,listingsutf8,documentation,breakable]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{varioref}
%
% command shell
\newtcblisting{commandshell}{colback=white,colupper=black,colframe=yellow!75
!black,listing only,listing options={style=tcblatex,language=sh},every listing
line={\textcolor{red}{\small\ttfamily\bfseries root \$> }}}
%
% Mots clés en couleur dans les listings
% Compiler avec pdflatex -shell-escape input
%


% Script entre un \begin et un \end avec caption
\newtcblisting[auto counter,number within=section]{mlstlisting}[1]{
listing engine=minted,minted style=default,minted language=python,
minted options={fontsize=\small,linenos,numbersep=3mm,mathescape},
colback=blue!3!white,colframe=blue!75!black,listing only,left=5mm,enhanced,
overlay={\begin{tcbclipinterior}\fill[red!20!blue!20!white] (frame.south west)
rectangle ([xshift=5mm]frame.north west);\end{tcbclipinterior}},breakable,
title=Script QuTiP \thetcbcounter: #1
}
%
% Script dans un fichier qu'on charge avec caption et label
\newtcbinputlisting[use counter from=mlstlisting]{\mlstinputlisting}[2][]{%
listing engine=minted,minted language=python,minted style=default,
minted options={fontsize=\small,linenos,numbersep=3mm,mathescape},
listing file={#2},
colback=violet!3!white,colframe=violet!85!black,fonttitle=\bfseries,
listing only,left=5mm,enhanced,
overlay={\begin{tcbclipinterior}\fill[red!20!blue!20!white] (frame.south west)
rectangle ([xshift=5mm]frame.north west);\end{tcbclipinterior}},breakable,
title=Script QuTiP \thetcbcounter: #1
}
% Output du Script précédent
\newtcbinputlisting[use counter from=mlstlisting]{\mclstinputlisting}[2][]{%
listing engine=minted,minted language=python,minted style=default,
minted options={fontsize=\small,linenos,numbersep=3mm,mathescape},listing
file={#2}, colback=blue!3!white,colframe=blue!60!white,fonttitle=\bfseries,
listing only,left=5mm,enhanced,
overlay={\begin{tcbclipinterior}\fill[red!20!blue!20!white] (frame.south west)
rectangle ([xshift=5mm]frame.north west);\end{tcbclipinterior}},breakable,
title=Script Ouput QuTiP \thetcbcounter: #1
}

%################################  ADDITIONAL (START)
\newenvironment{encapsmlstlisting}{%
  \begingroup\tcbverbatimwrite{\jobname.spectemp}%
}{\endtcbverbatimwrite\endgroup%
  \mlstinputlisting{\jobname.spectemp}%
}
%################################  ADDITIONAL (STOP)

% Procédure d'ouverture et de fermeture du fichier des solutions
%
\newcounter{texercise}
%
\newwrite\solout
\def\openoutsol{\immediate\openout\solout\jobname.sol}
\def\solfile#1{solutions/texercise#1.tex}
\def\writesol#1{\immediate\write\solout{\noexpand\processsol{\thetcbcounter}{#1}
}}%
\def\closeoutsol{\immediate\closeout\solout}
\def\inputsol{\IfFileExists{\jobname.sol}{\input{\jobname.sol}}{}}
%
% Excercises Style
\tcbset{
texercisestyle/.style={arc=0.5mm, colframe=blue!25!yellow!90!white,
colback=blue!25!yellow!5!white, coltitle=blue!25!yellow!40!black,
fonttitle=\small\sffamily\bfseries, fontupper=\small, fontlower=\small}
}
%
% Noyau de l'environnement Exercice avec les labels exercice (exe:#2) et
% solution (sol:#2)
\newtcolorbox[auto counter,number within=section,list inside=exam]%
{texercise}[2][]{texercisestyle,listing file={\solfile\thetcbcounter},
label={exe:#2},phantom={\writesol{#2}},title={Exercice
\thetcbcounter\hfill\mdseries Solution à la page \pageref{sol:#2}},
list entry={\protect\numberline{\thetcbcounter}Exercice avec solution à la
page \pageref{sol:#2}},breakable,#1}
%
%
% Solution part
% \usepackage{hyperref} % for \phantomsection
\newcommand{\processsol}[2]{%
  \tcbinputlisting{texercisestyle,text only,
    phantom={\phantomsection\label{sol:#2}},%
    title={Solution Exercice \ref{exe:#2} de la page \pageref{exe:#2}},
    listing file={\solfile{#1}},breakable}}
%
%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Macro des ``theorems'' colorés

% Théorème avec caption et label
\newcounter{mytheorem}[section]
\def\themytheorem{\thesection.\arabic{mytheorem}}

\tcbmaketheorem{theorem}{Théorème}{fonttitle=\bfseries\upshape,
  fontupper=\slshape,arc=0mm, colback=red!3,colframe=red!75!black,
  separator sign dash,breakable}
  {mytheorem}{th}
%
% Définition avec caption et label
\newcounter{mydefi}[section]
\def\themydefi{\thesection.\arabic{mydefi}}

\tcbmaketheorem{definition}{Définition}{fonttitle=\bfseries\upshape,
  fontupper=\slshape, arc=0mm, colback=blue!3,colframe=blue!75!black,
  separator sign dash,breakable}
  {mydefi}{df}
%
% Principe avec caption et label
\newcounter{myprinc}[section]
\def\themyprinc{\thesection.\arabic{myprinc}}

\tcbmaketheorem{principe}{Principe}{fonttitle=\bfseries\upshape,
  fontupper=\slshape, arc=0mm, colback=green!3,colframe=green!35!black,
  separator sign dash,breakable}
  {myprinc}{pr}
%
% Proposition avec caption et label
\newcounter{myprop}[section]
\def\themyprop{\thesection.\arabic{myprop}}

\tcbmaketheorem{proposition}{Proposition}{fonttitle=\bfseries\upshape,
  fontupper=\slshape, arc=0mm, colback=green!3,colframe=green!35!black,
  separator sign dash,breakable}
  {myprop}{prp}
%
% % Remarque avec caption et label
\newcounter{myrmq}[section]
\def\themyrmq{\thesection.\arabic{myrmq}}

\tcbmaketheorem{remark}{Remarque}{fonttitle=\bfseries\upshape,
  fontupper=\slshape, arc=0mm, colback=yellow!3,colframe=yellow!35!black,
  separator sign dash,breakable}
  {myrmq}{rq}

%
% % Exemple avec caption et label
\newcounter{myexpl}[section]
\def\themyexpl{\thesection.\arabic{myexpl}}

\tcbmaketheorem{example}{Exemple}{fonttitle=\bfseries\upshape,
  fontupper=\slshape, arc=0mm, colback=red!50!yellow!5!white,
colframe=red!50!yellow!50!black, separator sign dash,breakable}
  {myexpl}{exp}

%-----------------------------------------------------------------------
%
\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{30}
\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{0pt}

% Macro des abbréviations
\newenvironment{proof}[1][Preuve]{\noindent\textbf{#1.} }{\ \rule{0.5em}{0.5em}}
% Prise en compte du numéro de la section dans les différentes numérotations
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\numberwithin{figure}{section}
\numberwithin{table}{section}
% Ramener la typologie française à la typologie standard (anglo-saxone)
\frenchbsetup{StandardLayout}
% Défintion des commandes raccourcies personnelles
\newcommand{\opn}[1]{\ensuremath{\operatorname{#1}}} % Operatorname
\newcommand{\bls}[1]{\ensuremath{\boldsymbol{#1}}} %Boldsymbol
\newcommand{\av}[1]{\ensuremath{\langle{#1}\rangle}} %Average
\newcommand{\bra}[1]{\langle{#1}\vert} %Dirac ket
\newcommand{\ket}[1]{\vert{#1}\rangle} % Dirac bra
%
%
%
\begin{document}
\chapter{Calculs quantiques}

% Ouverture du fichier Solution
\openoutsol
%

\section{Interpreteur Spyder}


\begin{commandshell}
sudo apt-get install spyder
\end{commandshell}

\begin{texercise}{CX}
%
\begin{tcboutputlisting}
En vertu de la relation (\vref{eq:CX}), on a le script \texttt{IPhyton}
ci-dessous.
%########## CHANGED (begin)
\begin{encapsmlstlisting}
In [2]:
CX=tensor(basis(2,0)*basis(2,0).dag(),qeye(2))+tensor(basis(2,1)*basis(2,
1).dag(),sigmax())

In [3]: CX
Out[3]:
Quantum object: dims = [[2, 2], [2, 2]], shape = [4, 4], type = oper, isherm =
True
Qobj data =
[[ 1.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  1.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.  0.]]
\end{encapsmlstlisting}
%########## CHANGED (end)

\end{tcboutputlisting}
%
Proposer un script QuTiP, qui donne la matrice de la porte logique
quantique $CX$, sans utiliser la fonction \texttt{qutip.cnot}.
%
\end{texercise}

\begin{texercise}{separable_state}
%
\begin{tcboutputlisting}
%
The state (\vref{eq:GEntSt}) can be equivalently rewritten as
\begin{equation}
\ket{\psi}=a\{\ket{00}+b_0e^{i\varphi_0}\ket{01}+b_1e^{i\varphi_1}
\ket{10}+b_1b_0e^{i(\varphi_0+\varphi_1)}\ket{11}\}.
\label{eq:GEntSt2}
\end{equation}
The application of \texttt{CNOT}\ gate to (\vref{eq:GEntSt2}) leads to
\begin{equation}
\mathtt{CNOT}\ket{\psi}=a\{\ket{00}+b_0e^{i\varphi_0}\ket{01}+b_1
e^{i\varphi_1}\ket{11}+b_1b_0e^{i(\varphi_0+\varphi_1)}\ket{10}\}
\end{equation}
which is separable if and only if $b_0e^{i\varphi_0}=1$. Thus, \texttt{CNOT}
generated an entangled state if and only if at least one of the following 2
conditions is fulfiled:%
\begin{equation}
b_0\neq1,\,\varphi_0\neq0
\end{equation}

\end{tcboutputlisting}
%
The most general separable state of the two qubits can be written, up to an
overall phase, as%
\begin{equation}
\ket{\psi}=a(\ket{0} +b_1e^{i\varphi_1}\ket{1})\otimes(\ket{0}
+b_0e^{i\varphi_0}\ket{1}),
\label{eq:GEntSt}
\end{equation}
where $a$ is set to the completure. What conditions should the real
coefficients $b_0$, $b_1$, $\varphi_0$ and $\varphi_1$ satisfy in
order that $\mathtt{CNOT}\ket{\psi}$ be entangled?
%
\end{texercise}

% Fermeture du fichier Solution
\closeoutsol
%
%
\tcblistof[\subsection]{exam}{Solutions des Exercices%
  \label{listofexercises}}
  %
%   \newpage
% Charger les Solutions des Exercices du cours
 \inputsol
\end{document}
```

the messages :

[image]
I did not understand where the problem is ?

Comment: The error message is due to the `minted` option that you passed to `tcolorbox`. Since  `inted` uses `pygments`,  `shell-escape` is needed to allow lates to  run external commands from inside the tex file. See also: [What does --shell-escape do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88740/134144)

Comment: Here you can fin information on how to use `shell-escape` with different editors: [texmaker](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/236648/134144), [texstudio](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/99476/134144), [texworks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/187416/134144)

Comment: Thank you for posting a working example! At the same time, much of your code does not seem to be relevant to the question you're asking here. Please limit the example to only the code required for your issue to appear. You can have a look at [this guide for how to prune your code](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3225) for this purpose.